# Рисую на одной канве из двух потоков. Есть ли другой вариант чтобы не ждать пока канвас освободится

Tags: java, android, canvas

Игра отрисовывается на канве и есть такой примерно код реализации секундомера.

```
while(true)(
   Tread.sleep(1);
   millisec++;
   class.onDraw1(canvas,millisec)// тут читаю строку и рисую изображения цифр.
```

Далее код могу и не писать, этого достаточно, чтобы задать вопрос. Если этот код приписать в поток игрового цикла, то он будет почти всё время спать. И сам цикл на выполнение тратит время и точного секундомера мне не получить.  Если сделать еще один поток и как то получать доступ к канве, которая объявлена в потоке игрового цикла, то все равно либо канва будет lock в игровом потоке, либо мне придется ее самому все время лочить, через каждую миллисекунду, чтобы рисовать время.

Отсюда вопрос, как решить эту проблему?

Пока писал пришли такие мысли: раз верхняя строка игрового поля все равно для красоты, то может эту часть рисовать на другой канве в другом потоке? Но придется размеры тщательно подгонять, а тут еще и разные разрешения экранов.
Еще мысль: в  `Layout` в `ImageView` отрисовывать канву, а сверху этого `ImageView` еще один расположить, Если даже так можно, то из-за разных потоков, то один сверху будет отрисовываться то другой.  Выходит не наложить,  а так же расположить рядом.

Какой вариант вам кажется лучше и какие еще варианты решения есть.  И кстати, Если рисовать на `Layout`, то я могу использовать объект `Chronometer` , а могу я его изображения цифр на свои поменять

Comment: сделайте один поток, который берет данные из модели и отображает изменения. остальные потоки могут менять модель как им необходимо. и синхронизироваться они так же должны на модели.

Comment: Под моделью вы говорите о layout ? И как же остальные будут изменять как угодно?  Чтобы один изменил другой должен ждать пока освободится canvas , а он будет занят через каждую миллисекунду. Нужно чтобы он был всегда свободен. Поэтому на одной канве рисовать не получится.  Хотя я могу пропускать кадры для секундомера и синхронизироваться.  Только как правильно синхронизировать,но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: под моделью я подразумеваю модель из MVC. модель - это описание состояния приложения (или его части).

Comment: Я патеррны вообще не читал еще, первую игру решил без них. Ну MVC в общем я понял.  И модель в нем это классы где будет храниться результат расчетов игровой ситуации.  Допустим поток 1 считает положение персонажа, поток 2 через каждую миллисекунду изменяет данные о времени. И поток 3  считывает одни данные сделанные в потоке 2,другие в потоке 1 и 30 раз в секунду (30фпс) выводит их на экран. Я понял. Сейчас намучаюсь с синхронизацией и получением даных с одного класса в другом. Плохо разбираюсь еще в этом.

Comment: вы потом может дать ответ на свой же вопрос и выбрать его как правильный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если уж я захотел рисовать всё  на канве, то делаю так: каждую миллисекунду пытаться получить доступ к канве на которой возможно уже рисует другой поток, бессмысленно по крайней мере потому что в 1000 раз в секунду обновиться экран физически не сможет.  60 кадров в секунду значит, время можно выводить через каждые примерно 16 миллисекунд. И то вариант с попыткой рисовать с двух разныз потоков на одной канве не верен. То что надо нарисовать на секундомере хранить в переменной и изменять ее в одном потоке,  а рисовать значение этой переменной с другого потока.  Всё согласно паттерну MVC. Переменные наша модель,  канва - представление, а контроллер тот поток, которые запрашивает переменные на отрисовку.и классы которые вычисляют эти переменные я думаю тоже относятся к модели, исправьте если я не прав.